# Pfsense Openvpn site to site subnet

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

Site A Pfsense
    *192.168.0.0*

Site B Pfsense
    *192.168.0.0*

Can OpenVPN Link A<>B, or should i use different subnet for A and B ?

(like 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.1.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different subnets. Otherwise, your equipment has no idea if the 192.168.0.13 it's addressing is the one local or the one across the VPN (and tends to go for the local one - it's closer.)

Preferably, move away from the over-used defaults, it saves trouble. 192.168.157.X and 192.168.158.X, to pick a couple of under-used but perfectly valid nets at random.

Answer (score 0):

You **must** use different subnets for any VPN to work. Just imagine what happens when a packet addressed to, say, 192.168.0.15, reaches one of the two routers: how can the router possibly know whether the packet is destined for its WAN side or for its LAN side?

Let me however give you a slightly different suggestion: change the subnets of **both** nets, if you only can. At some point in your life, you will want to connect to a different VPN, perhaps at work, or will try to use your own VPN from a cafè or a hotel. You will find then that most LANs are configured by inexperienced users as either *192.168.0.0/24* or *192.168.1.0/24*. For this reason, it proves expedient, if not outright clair-voyant, to change your LANs' subnets to something extremely unusual, something like *192.168.211.0/24* and *10.11.207.0/24*, say. It will make your life easier, in the short run.

Comment: @cyrianox You can upvote it, if you like it.

Comment: nop, need 15 reputation to "like"